# How do I make the terminal run python 3.1?

Tags: command-line, python

Currently, when I type "python" at the terminal I get v2.6 which is all fine and dandy but how can I set it to use v3.1 instead?  Is there a "path" variable out there somewhere that I can change like windows?

**EDIT:** I already have python3 installed and up and running.  I just want to know how to set it as the shells default python version.

Comment: **python3** vs **python** from the command line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [python-virtualenv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/python-virtualenv)  to create a virtual python environment.

Select the version of Python to be created in the virtual environment:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.1 myvirtualenv
```

To manage multiple virtual Python environments, install the [virtualenvwrapper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/virtualenvwrapper) extension.

[Why virtualenv?](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

> The basic problem being addressed is one of dependencies and versions, and indirectly permissions. Imagine you have an application that needs version 1 of LibFoo, but another application requires version 2. How can you use both these applications? If you install everything into /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages (or whatever your platform's standard location is), it's easy to end up in a situation where you unintentionally upgrade an application that shouldn't be upgraded.

Comment: If my app ever goes public I will definitely use this thank you.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you need to install the `python3` package. After installing it, go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

then choose python3 from the list that's presented.

If it does not work, you may need to recreate the symlink. First save it:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/pythonSAVE
```

afterwards, create the alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install python2.5 python /usr/bin/python2.5 2
sudo update-alternatives --install python3.1 python /usr/bin/python3.1 1
```

create a new symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/python /usr/bin/python
```

Finally, choose the one (python3) you want to use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

And if you need to go back to python2, just repeat the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

I guess just install the package and update-alternatives will work very well, you may don't need to recreate links from scratch. Thanks!

EDIT: As pointed out [here](https://serverfault.com/a/158986) the `update-alternatives` with the `--install` options accepts an absolute link, so you may need to run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.5 2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.1 1
```

Comment: I tried running `sudo update-alternatives --config python`, but it tells me `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python.` I tried recreating the symlink as you said but it doesn't semm to change anything... What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First install Python 3.1 using the dead snakes repository: https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes

Then you can type 'python3' at the command line to run Python 3.1 while retaining the normal system Python.

Comment: +1 - Seems pointless, since `python3.1-minimal` is in the Ubuntu repositories, but actually this repository contains `python2.4` and `python2.5` - which is rather nice. (I have to use python 2.4 for high performance computing, know the pain...)