# How to default to newest version of Python?

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, default-programs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make the terminal run python 3.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14615/how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1)

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and just installed Python 3.1 but entering python on my Gnome Terminal gets me Python 2.6 . How to fix it to get Python 3.1 on typing python on the terminal ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't sanction Dayjay's answer at all. Replacing Python system-wide could make applications hugely unstable and in a lot of cases, they'll just break.

- Python-based libraries are installed to a version-specific place (eg `/usr/lib/python2.6/`) so swapping in a new version without catering for existing packages will break things that need things on the right Python path.
- There are **major** language differences between 2.6 and 3.x that, if a package doesn't check to see what version it's using (common of older scripts) could make things unstable.

  For example, if you divide two `int`s in 2.6 you are returned a floored `int`; but in 3.x it'll return a `float`.

The safest thing to do is just call the 3.x binary when you want to use Python 3.x.

```
python3.1 my_python_script.py
```

Comment: You are right , but his answer is probably ok for my specific scenario which is a lot less critical then you might suspect. I have just installed a Ubuntu guest OS  on a virtual box (hosted by Windows 7 ) at my home PC. The whole point is to play around with the distro including the use of Gnome terminal and  Python 3 in Linux. It does not matter even if the whole system is screwed... its used as a toy anyway. I did use the python3.1 command on the shell , and it worked well ... but was a little inconvenient. So I wanted to just use the python command for the 3.1 version.

Comment: By the way, if it were a critical situation, then  what would you suggest to reverse what I did by changing the symlink. Simply execute the inverse commands and restore the symlink to Python 2.6 ?

Comment: Yeah, just delete the symlink again and make a new one back to `/usr/bin/python2.6`

Comment: One funny thing (probably a major system screw up) that I noticed after the original redirection of the link to Python 3.1 was that the Ubuntu Software Center wont start on clicking..... it just wont , even after reinstalling the Ubuntu Softwar Center. 
Now when I reversed the default version to Python 2.6 ... it started to work again ... lolz ... yeah that was fun !!

Answer (score -2):

You could simply change the symlink:

```
rm /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.1 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer is getting downvoted. He wanted to run python 3.1 if he types `python` (for any reasons), thats exactly what it does.

Comment: I wouldn't say that changing the symlink is a security concern, but editing system files (including symlinks to system files) without understanding **exactly** what they do and **why** they do it that way can expose a user to a lot of problems that they might not be able to solve.