# Running .py python scripts from the command line using python3

Tags: command-line, python3

I am currently able to run .py python scripts from a terminal due, I believe, to this inclusion in my .profile file:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/myplace/python
```

*python* being the directory where I put all my home rolled scripts.  The thing is that the default interpreter is python 2 and I'd like to be able to run python 3 scripts the same way.  Is there a way to indicate in a .py script which interpreter to use?  I've seen ample warnings against changing the default interpreter and it's not something I want to do anyway.

TIA

Comment: Please add your answer as answer not in the body question. See also: http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change my PYTHONPATH to make 3,2 my default Python instead of 2.7.2?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103469/how-do-i-change-my-pythonpath-to-make-3-2-my-default-python-instead-of-2-7-2)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate as it is not about changing the default Python version but to use another version for some scripts.

Comment: I say specifically in the question that I do not want to change the default interpreter.  There are many warnings that this might break certain tools that depend on Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

And to answer my own question for the benefit of anybody else barking up the wrong tree, it's a simple matter of putting the location of the interpreter in a shebang at the top of the script:

```
#! /opt/python3/bin/python3.x
```

or some such depending on your particular installation.