# easy_install with different python

Tags: python, version

I'm trying to *easily install* packages to my *newly installed* Python3 on the latest Ubuntu release.

At present it uses python2.7 be default, so all of my easy_installs will put the packages into */usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*. Obviously if I want to install the various packages in the new version via easy_install, it won't do this.

1. Assuming easy_install is python specific, how do I specify which easy_install to use (or, how do I tell easy_install to switch Python)?
2. Can you think of an easier way to do this? I've discovered *virtualenv* but don't think it's what I'm after.

Edit1: I've actually just noticed that after installing *Distribute* with the 'Python3' command, it has a /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/easy-install.pth however I can't execute it. Doing a *which easy_install* gives /usr/local/bin/easy_install.

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but I prefer `pip` over `easy_install`. `pip` has some nice additional features like `pip uninstall`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Chose which version of python to use

#### python 2.x

```
python setup.py install
```

#### python 3.x

```
python3 setup.py install
```

### Change the system's default python version

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

---

#### Additional Information

[How do I make the terminal run python 3.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14615/how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1)