# Is it safe to change the system python3 to point to python3.4 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, python3

I've installed python3.4 from the [deadsnakes repo](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes), and I'd like to make it my default python3 (which is currently python3.2). Is it safe to simply change the python3 link?

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python3
```

Are there system components that would die due to an inability to work with python3.4 instead of python3.2?

Comment: Why not [`virtualenv`](http://askubuntu.com/a/14622/158442)? Seems much safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do that

- `python3.4` will not find modules installed in places like `/usr/lib/python3.2/`. That includes all modules installed by the package manager.
- modules containing binary libs compiles against Python 2.3 will likely not work without recompiling.

That means that almost all programs from the official repositories needing Python3 will stop working.