# Using Python 2.6 while python 2.7 is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an application which when I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
paraview: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already have python 2.7 installed. When I type `python`, I can write codes. It seems it needs Python 2.6. I download and install the python 2.6 by downloading it and running:

```
./configure
make -j6
make checkinstall
```

But when I look for `libpython2.6.so*` in my computer, no files are found and still the application is crying for that. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: See here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/14615/how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the shared Python2.6 library. It does not get build by default, that is why it's not there after you build and installed Python 2.6

Two options: Build new *with* shared library or install a pre-build package.

1. To compile with the shared lib, do pretty much what you did in the first place, but configure with `--enable-shared`

   ```
   ./configure --enable-shared
   make -j6
   sudo checkinstall
   sudo ldconfig
   ```

   The library should be installed to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` or something similar like `/usr/local/lib` and thus be found by the loader. The last command makes the dynamic loader aware of the new library.
2. Python2.6 is not in the Ubuntu repositories anymore, but you can install it from `ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`.

   1. Remove your previous build. Since you installed with `checkinstall`, this is painless.
   2. Add the repo `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`
   3. Install `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libpython2.6`
   4. (Maybe) If `libpython2.6` is not enough, install `python2.6` and `python2.6-dev`

Comment: How should I install them in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`?

Comment: @mmostajab You don't. They get installed automatically by `make install` or `checkinstall`.

Comment: but still after the `checkinstall`, I still have the same issue while the python2.6 is installed and the library is in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6`

Comment: @mmostajab Sorry, after installing you probably have to do `sudo ldconfig` to make the loader aware of the new libraries. I have updated my answer.