# Replacing python2 with python3 in terminal?

Tags: command-line, python

How do I replace python2 with py3 in my gnome terminal? Would

```
alias python='python3'
```

work? Thanks!

Comment: well yes it would work, but what's the problem just calling `python3` ? Do you really grudge that one keystroke? If you need to call python 2 you would have to do `python2.7` (two extra keystrokes)!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14615/how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1?rq=1

Comment: It seems nothing in the linked post is needed since we have python3 already and can call it with `python3`

Comment: Don't do it. Ubuntu chose to go with a convention where there is "python" and "python3". Developers rely on this, so you might break something. You should view python2 and python3 as separate programming languages with separate, incompatible runtimes.

Comment: @Zanna 2.7 is three extra ;)

Comment: @Zacharee1 I mean the net is 2 extra - you saved one dropping `3` but gained 3 adding `2.7`

Comment: @Zanna Actually you don't need to type `python2.7`, there is also just `python2`.

Comment: you're right @ByteCommander - I did `readlink $(which python)` to go one level and I get `2.7`

Comment: @Zanna Yes, but there should also be a `python2` pointing to `python2.7` as well.

Comment: yes there is, as I said, you are right :) @ByteCommander I was just explaining my conclusion

Comment: What is the use case of this? You are certainly free to create any Bash aliases you want but this one doesn't seem particularly useful and may create more confusion than good.

Comment: I want to "migrate" to python3 so to say. I do not wanna use python2 in the cli or the bash script I run with my shell/terminal @edwinksl

Comment: The alias would not work in a script, but your system will just break if you make any lower level interventions that would do that

Comment: @Zanna I know this, that's why I want to do this explicit for the cli commands and the bash/terminal I am running

Comment: Well make your alias, if you want, put in your `.bashrc`,  like my first comment said, it will work. And like Byte Commander said, you can then just call `python2` if necessary

Comment: Is it yet possible that I replace python2 with python3 at all in my system? Just asking...

Comment: What do you mean by "replace"? If you mean to completely uninstall Python 2 and just keep Python 3 in your system, that is not possible and it will break your system if you do try. If you mean to change the `python` symlink to point to `python3` instead of `python2`, then you also risk things going wrong because many programs and scripts assume `python` is `python2`. You can still have a Bash alias like @Zanna said, but my argument against this is it is doing more harm than good where the only good here is merely saving a single keystroke.

Comment: The alias will not be harmful as it will work only in interactive shells, but like @edwinksl explains,  any deeper intervention will break stuff on your system. Many programs in Ubuntu use python2 and many use python3, any they are not at all the same.

Comment: To clarify, by harm, I really meant confusion. Suppose you did define the Bash alias you wanted and you now want to run a script that has been `chmod +x`'ed. The potential confusion here is that one might get too used to thinking that `python` is `python3` and then get confused by a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang, thinking that the Python 3 interpreter   is being invoked when it is really still the Python 2 version of it that is invoked. By defining this alias, you now have to constantly remind yourself `python` is `python3` only in your own interactive shells and not anywhere else.

Comment: @КристиянКацаров Here is an example of why you shouldn't do the aliasing in your post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/833367/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-use-anacondas-python-instead-of-previous-python-installa#comment1271523_833367. You will eventually get confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to replace Python. Use

```
python
```

for Python 2 and

```
python3
```

for Python 3 when calling your script.

Comment: what if I want python3 to be default?

Comment: can you explain why you want to set python 3 as default? for what are you using python?

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, changing `python` to point to `python3` system-wide could cause troubles and is probably not a good idea. However, if you only really want this behavior for a certain project, you could consider using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) to set what `python` means within a particular directory. It's not in the repos, but it's relatively straightforward to set up following the github page. Once you have `pyenv` installed and setup,

```
pyenv versions
```

will list the python versions you have installed. Then to set `python` to point to the system's `python3` *only for the local directory* (see [doc](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local)), you can use

```
pyenv local 3.5.2
```

(assuming 16.04, or whatever `python3` appears in the output of the `pyenv versions` command).

Note, `virtualenv` which is in the repos can also be used to similar effect. See a comparison [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950300/what-is-the-relationship-between-virtualenv-and-pyenv).